webpack build not working in prod, working in dev, [widget-bundle.js] file in the _next/static/chunks folder
I was building a website widget that can be embedded using a script in websites. My build is in next.js [typescript] using the webpack module. using next.config.js

Now the issue is with the build output of the widget-bundle.js module inside my .next/static/chunks folder, where the widget-bundle.js is created when i run 'npm run build/dev' commands.
The issue is that the code inside this 'widget-bundle.js' is not same in dev and prod build. In dev build, it using eval-source-map and creating this file - Github Gist for npm run dev - the widget loads on screen for this.
While for npm run build, it created this file for widget-bundle.js - Github gist for npm run build - and the widget doesn't load.

Sharing my github repo for reference - https://github.com/SuprSend-NotificationAPI/bifrost
I think the issue is inside the next.config.js file.
but anyways, do share your views where might be the issue.
Also sharing the network console screenshot for both the prod and dev versions. In dev version youll see the size of the bundle-widget.js is more
npm run dev code for widget-bundle.js
While in this prod one, its much less.
npm run build for widget-bundle.js
P.S. In next.config.js file I have tried to undo the hashing in the path of widget-bundle.js becuase in prod mode it formed at a different location with the url hash, and when tried to run it, the location of the file in browser Network console wasnt matching.

Tried changing the webpack config for both dev/prod mode (like eval, source-map, (none) ) - still same results.
Tried to deploy on Vercel, as it has its inbuilt webpack bundlers, it still didnt worked.


You can checkout my vercel deployed page for Network tab inspection, particularly head to the location of 'widget-bundle.js' where you will see some code, which is completely different in 'npm run dev' mode as I shared the above Github gists. Here is the vercel link - https://bifrost-dun.vercel.app/test-widget

Here is my next.config.js file
const path = require('path');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  const BUILD_ID = Date.now();

  return {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
      domains: ['cdn-b.saashub.com', 'randomuser.me'],
    },

    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      // No source maps generated, optimizing for production
      config.devtool = false;

      if (!isServer) {
        const originalEntry = config.entry;
        config.entry = async () => {
          const entries = await originalEntry();
          
          if (!entries['widget-bundle']) {
            entries['widget-bundle'] = {
              import: path.resolve(__dirname, 'widget-entry.tsx'),
              dependOn: undefined,
            };
          }
          
          return entries;
        };

        // Ensure the split chunks configuration is set up
        if (!config.optimization.splitChunks) {
          config.optimization.splitChunks = {};
        }
        
        config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
          ...config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups,
          widgetBundle: {
            name: 'widget-bundle',
            test: /widget-entry\.tsx$/,
            chunks: 'all',
            enforce: true,
          },
        };

        // Apply cache-busting filename pattern across all environments
        config.output.filename = (pathData) => {
          return pathData.chunk.name === 'widget-bundle'
            ? `static/chunks/[name].js?v=${BUILD_ID}`
            : 'static/chunks/[name].[contenthash].js';
        };

        config.output.chunkFilename = (pathData) => {
          return pathData.chunk.name === 'widget-bundle'
            ? `static/chunks/[name].js?v=${BUILD_ID}`
            : 'static/chunks/[name].[contenthash].js';
        };
      }

      return config;
    },
  };
};

module.exports = nextConfig;


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
